# java code how to read null values in csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have csv in file containing multiple rows.If first column value is nothing its is giving error and m not able to insert in database.
ex
If row is :130,1,datafile8.csv, 2007 ,17,List_date no problem in reading n inserting
but if row is: ,0,datafile8.csv,Bihar,7,list_Left ,not able to read n insert .how to insert null in above row .so i can insert dis row in database.

```
String keyword = "celldescription.csv";
File makefile = new File(keyword);
  BufferedReader r2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(makefile));
  strLine1 = r2.readLine();
   System.out.println (strLine1);
   String r="0";int r1=0;

  while((strLine1=r2.readLine())!=null)
   {
  System.out.println (strLine1);

  StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(strLine1, ",");
  // Print the content on the console


        String cellvalue = st2.nextToken();          


        String position = st2.nextToken();


        String Docid=st2.nextToken();


        String Word=st2.nextToken();


        String Count=st2.nextToken();

        String List_Entry=st2.nextToken();


        String tab3="insert into description(cellvalue,position,Docid,Word,Count,List_Entry) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(tab3);
        ps.setString (1,cellvalue );
        ps.setString (2,position );
        ps.setString (3,Docid);
        ps.setString (4,Word );
        ps.setString (5,Count );
        ps.setString (6,List_Entry );
        ps.executeUpdate();



 }//end of while



  r2.close();

 System.out.println("Data is inserted");

        }//try closed**
```

Comment: I haven't seen `StringTokenizer` in code for quite awhile. You may want to consider using `String.split(",")` instead.

Comment: Is it difficult to add a null checking? hmm..

Comment: Also, CSV is quite more complicated that it seems (quoted values that include separators, and so on). I would suggest using a third party API, Apache has one that looks good.

Comment: I used a StringTokenizer just the other week, it was quaint.

Comment: And many databases have tools to directly import csv file.

Comment: @SJuan76 - good point, it is indeed better to use a proven library to handle CSV.

Answer (score 2):

When your `String strLine1` starts with comma(,) `StringTokenizer` omit empty string if it is in start or end or even in between.

Ex - `,0,datafile8.csv,Bihar,7,list_Left`

token -> `"0" - "datafile8.csv" - "Bihar" - "7" and "list_Left"`

better you split the string by comma(,).
Ex -

```
String[] str = strLine1.split(",",-1);
```

str[] -> `["","datafile8.csv","Bihar","7" and "list_Left"]`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a java library for your work with csv files.
[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is one, it helped me a lot.

Some of its features:

> - Arbitrary numbers of values per line
> - Ignoring commas in quoted elements
> - Handling quoted entries with embedded carriage returns (ie    entries that span multiple lines)
> - Configurable separator and quote characters (or use sensible defaults)
> - Read all the entries at once, or use an Iterator style model
> - Creating csv files from String[] (ie. automatic escaping of embedded quote chars)